# Current uploaded image not set on exact position after converted canvas into image in html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to exact image after converted from canvas. I am uploading multiple image into canvas with [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), After uploading multiple images converted canvas into image, But last image not fix in desire position.

**Uploaded Image:**

[image]

**After click Me**:
[image]

**Code:**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'jpeg', quality: 0.8 });

      console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
      document.getElementById('txt').href=dataURL;
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="file">
<a href="" id="txt">Click Me!!</a>
```

Please check JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/8gt6d7op/5/

Please give me some Idea.

Comment: I can't see the problem. Maybe you did more steps that you didn't tell us about them. Please specify the all steps (include "I dragged the first image then uploaded one more" etc)

Comment: @Mosh Feu. After upload image, I am trying move to another place in canvas. When i am clicking Click me!! then uploaded image show in by default same place(Not draggable place). Please see above two screen shot( Car image) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the this issue correctly..

**The problem**

You set the `href` attribute once when the `upload input` change. If after this you change anything the value of the attribute `href` doesn't change.

**The solution**

Get the dataURI from the canvas when you click on the link, **then** generate the dataURI and show the correct image.

**The full code**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'jpeg', quality: 0.8 });

      //console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
      //document.getElementById('txt').href=dataURL;
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
});

document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="file">
<a href="#" id="txt">Click Me!!</a>
<br />
<img id="preview" />
```

**Note:** After you click on "Click Me!!" I show the image at the bottom of the page instead of redirect the user to the image "page". In this way you can easily see the changes and don't need to reload the page in each time.

**Update:**

Now in the snippet before you export the image, the function make all the element inside the `canvas` deactivate so their border will remove. Thanks to: [How to remove borders and corners from Canvas object? [Fabric.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154005/how-to-remove-borders-and-corners-from-canvas-object-fabric-js)

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck!

Comment: @MoshFeu I keep rejecting your tag wiki edit since you made a typo: farbic.js. I recreated the correct one and copied your explanation into that tag...

Comment: @ChrisMaes I guess that you recreate the tag `farbic.js` BUT  I was double check this again and the name of the library `fabricjs` and the website is http://fabricjs.com/.

Comment: So do I. (I think) Which tag I created?

Comment: @Mosh Feu. If you don't mind i have one more question. I want to remove outline(blue line coordinates) from current uploaded image.

Comment: @Mosh Feu. Thank you.